# KERNELBASE.dll throws application stopped working

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am running a Deployed Winform application developed in .NET 3.5 .While opening the application windows throws Application Stopped working . My EventLog shows

> Faulting application name: MyApp.exe, version: 1.0.0.0, time stamp:
>   0x540175e5 Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version:
>   6.1.7601.17625, time stamp: 0x4de876e8 Exception code: 0xe0434352 Fault offset: 0x0000d36f Faulting process id: 0x11c4 Faulting
>   application start time: 0x01cfc661651bac27 Faulting application path:
>   C:\Program Files\MyApp\MyApp.exe Faulting module path:
>   C:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll Report Id:
>   d28a5135-3254-11e4-93c9-eca86b7993c9

What i tried is

1. Checked missing runtime directories
2. Run as Administrator
3. Clean solution and after that manually added all references and deployed

Does it a compatibility issue ? How do i address that ?

Comment: I found a couple links that may solve your problem if they apply to you. http://social.answers.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/excslcreate/thread/9596d648-e843-482c-a328-5d690fc18bef and http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-performance/programs-crash-error-fault-module-kernelbasedll/9fe5d2e7-79d0-42c1-b8dc-51ed8d70f749

Comment: This sounds more like corruption of the system. Are you able to produce a minimal sample that reproduces the error, or does it only appear on one computer? Also, make sure you have .NET 3.5 installed. .NET 4.0 is a completely separate runtime. Note that `Exception code: 0xe0434352` is a .NET exception, so you might want to add an `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException` handler and log the .NET exception. And of course, if you install a debugger, you'll be able to attach it when the exception occurs and you'll see where and why it happens.

Comment: Thanks for the reply . Now i noticed first time it is running and second time not running . Even after closing the application the Task Manager shows application running . After forced to close the app in Task Manager its opening from explorer . I got the problem but dont know how to fix it ....

Comment: Force to close (Environment.Exit) worked